# Why am I getting an IE style DNS error page on Chrome for only one domain?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, dns, internet-explorer

The site is http://northwestpharmacy.com, and I am only getting this old, IE-style error page on my home computer on all browsers.  No other sites are bringing up this page, and even the subdomain of http://blog.northwestpharmacy.com works fine.  There's nothing weird in my hosts file.  What could possibly be causing this?

[image: Weird old-school DNS error page]

Comment: Not reproducible on my machine. (Internet Explorer 10, Windows 7 32-bit)

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be my ISP.  It's for any computer on my network.